# JavaScript module pattern and this

Tags: javascript, node.js, module-pattern

I've started to experiment with Node and i've worked within a single file.
This is the basic principle of my code:

```
function Validation(){
    this.a = function(){...}
    this.b = function(){...}
    return this;
}

var validation = Validation();

(function(){
    models["a"] = {
        validate: [a, b]
    }
}).call(validation);
```

This works perfectly fine. Now i want to move the Validation function to it's own file, validation.js. Therefore i change my code to this:

```
/* validation.js */
function Validation(){
    this.a = function(){...}
    this.b = function(){...}
    return this;
}

module.exports.Validation = new Validation();


/*  Main file */
var validation = require('./validation');

(function(){
    models["a"] = {
        validate: [a, b]
    }
}).call(validation);
```

When i try to run this code, i get error "ReferenceError: a is not defined".
I can solve this by changing `a` to `this.a`, but why did it work before without the `this` keyword?

Comment: Simply because the IIFE is called in the context of `validation`, and `a` tells JS to scan the scopes (current and up, all the way to global) for a _variable_ called `a`. `this.a` tells JS to look for a _property_ called `a` in the prototype chain of the context object, ie `Validation`. You could've written `(function(){ validation.a;}());`. `validation` will be resolved to the global `var validation`, and I'm accessing its `a` property

Comment: If you're only ever constructing the validation object once, why are you using a constructed object at all?

Answer (score 2):

`Validation` (without `new` keyword) is not a constructor, so using `this` inside of it you deal with global object context.

Try this instead:

```
function Validation() {
    return {
        a: function() {...},
        b: function() {...}
    };
}
```

Or otherwise use `module.exports.Validation = new Validation()`;

In addition to your actual question. You have to use `this.a` because there are no local scope variables exported and available as `a` and `b` (it happens with global object though). You could of course use `with` (`with (this) models["a"] = {validate: [a, b]})` but it's good idea to use it at all. So the answer is that you have to use `this.a`.

Comment: Sorry, i was actually doing it like the second thing you said. Just a typo in my simplified example.

Comment: Did you try the first approach?

Comment: Yes but it gives the exact same result.

Comment: @dfsq: You're not answering the actual question: why `a` needs to be `this.a`.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't it work without the `this`? Simple, as I stated in my comment:

Simply because the IIFE is called in the context of `validation`, but your use of `a` tells JS to scan the scopes (current and up, all the way to global) for a *variable* called `a`.
`this.a` tells JS to look for a *property* called `a` in the prototype chain of the context object, ie `Validation`.

You could've written

```
(function()
{
    models["a"] = {
        validate: [a, b]
    };
}());
```

`validation` will be resolved to the global `var validation` through scope-scanning. Then, you're simply accessing the `a` property, just like you are now, through `this.a`.

*Note:*
Writing `models["a"]` inside your IIFE doesn't add up: `models` is, as your code stands, an *implied* global, which is evil!
It would appear that `models` is an object, though, but I can't see why you would set a property using the bracket notation, why not write:

```
var models = {a: { validate: [this.a, this.b]}};//local var
models.a = { validate: [this.a, this.b]};//global
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two major errors.

```
module.exports.Validation = Validation();
```

Calls the function `Validation` (without a new `this`) and export the returned object as `Validation`.

```
var validation = require('./validation').Validation();
```

Calls the exported `Validation`, which is not a function, but the object you created above.

Most likely, you want to export the constructor, and then use it to construct an object?

```
module.exports = Validation;
...
var Validation = require('./validation');
var obj = new Validation();
```

Comment: You fail to address the actual issue: why the OP needs `this.a` instead of `a`

Comment: The actual issue is an apparent misunderstanding of how modules work. Knowing the details of `this` isn't useful, as it will still be wrong.